# Why do I get this 'Use of undeclare identifier addressbook' error?

Tags: ios4

```
NSArray* allPersons = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

I get a `Use of undeclare identifier addressbook` error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting answers your question. You are passing `addressBook` to the function, but you haven't defined `addressBook`.